# Wrong Encoding after Converting .txt to .sql File

Tags: java, mysql, file, encoding, filereader

I've got a *.txt* File, which contains millions of postalcodes.
There are all well-formatted (readable).
My Goal is, to import the postalcodes into a MySql-Database.
I need to convert the postalcodes from the *.txt* File into a *.sql* File.

I wrote an **Java** Application to Convert the important parts into an SQL-File.

**EDIT:** The *.txt* File contains many information. That's why I want to read the File (In Java), filter the File content and finally create a *.sql* File. Many thanks to any Solution written in "Python, SQL, C++, BrainF***" or other languages, but I would appreciate a Solution for my specific **Java** Code.
The *.txt* File uses UTF-8 encoding.

After convert into ".sql", the content has several issues.
For Example the Cyrillic Character "Я" is not "*known*" in the SQL-File.
I assume, that the encoding is wrong.
It would be nice, if someone could help me to get a clue how to resolve this.

TXT-File:
[TXT-File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVwP0.png)

SQL-File: [SQL-File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTm9A.png)

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(GeoData.class.getResource(sourceFilenameInput.getText().trim()).getFile().trim()))) {
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            GeoData geoData = new GeoData();
            geoData.addOrt(getPlaceFromFile(line));
        }
```

getPlaceFromFile Method:

```
private String getPlaceFromFile(String line) {
    String[] placeHolder = line.split("\t");
    if (placeHolder .length > 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < placeHolder .length - 2; i++) {
            if (!placeHolder [i + 2].trim().isEmpty() && placeHolder [i + 2].trim().length() > 3) {
                return filterPlace(placeHolder [i + 2].trim(), "'", "\\", "^", ";", "*", "|");
            }
        }
    }
    return "EMPTY";
}
```

FilterPlace Method:

```
private String filterPlace(String place, String... filter) {
    String newPlace = place;
    for (String string : filter) {
        if (newPlace .trim().contains(string))
            newPlace = newPlace .trim().replace(string, " ");
    }
    return newPlace;
}
```

What have I tried so far?
I replaced the `FileReader` with an `InputStreamReader` and used the `FileInputStream` with the Charset *UTF-8*. After converting in UTF-8 the SQL-File looked like this:
[UTF8 Converted SQL-FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILuay.png)

Comment: Can you get the hex of a line in the .txt file that has `Я`?

Comment: `D18F я  D0AF Я` -- You are asking about uppercase YA, but showing lowercase YA.

Comment: Hex of the complete String from line 6: c390e2809dc391e282acc391efbfbdc390c2bdc390c2bac390c2bec390c2b2c390c2b5c391e280a0202f2044726a616e6b6f766563

Comment: The Я was just an example... there are more Cyrillic Characters, which are unknown (as described in my Question)

Comment: Doing away with the old utility classes FileReader and FileWriter is just fine. Just the small Cyrillic ya seems to have been corrupted. Do you somewhere have a `new String(string.getBytes(str, ...), ...)` / something with 0x8F?

Comment: Nope, not using any "new String" and / or "str.getBytes(..., ..)". What you see is what I use (Code).

Comment: Still not resolved... still no clue. For all new answers: Please read the Question and what Code I'm using. I'm **not** using any "hidden"-Code neither I'm "hiding" any Code. This simple Lines are all I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer.

I just edited the encoding Format from eclipse to solve the Problem.

`Workspace` > `Preferences` > `General` > click on `Workspace` and edit the `Text file encoding` from `Cp1252` to `UTF-8`.

Thats all and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the .txt columns are split on `\t`, do not convert before loading.  Instead simply use the [`LOAD DATA INFILE ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) SQL statement, something like

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'the_file.txt'
     INTO tablename
     CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
     COLUMNS TERMINATED BY "\t"
     LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
     (col1, zip, name);
```

I don't know how to run that from Java.  But none of the code you presented should be needed.

Your comment has some garbage in it --

```
E2808B     8203=x200B  [​]   BN  ZERO WIDTH SPACE
E2808C     8204=x200C  [‌]   BN  ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
```

(I spotted it by double clicking on the hex to copy it.  But it stopped in the middle!)

`Д` is hex `D094`, but if you [*double encode*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) it, you get hex `C390 E2809D`.  See that link for likely causes of such.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand your Answer... I don't know what you exactly want from me.

Comment: Please show me, where I encode in my whole Code. I can't find it.

Comment: Toss your conversion code and use `LOAD DATA` instead.  If you still get `C3...` instead of `D0...`, then read about "double encoding".  You have not set "utf8" in all the places needed.

Comment: (Don't worry about the E2...; fix the rest.)

Comment: You're being cryptic now, Rick. Where should I add "LOAD DATA"?? I really don't get it. It would be nice, if you could be more specific. For Example: "Hey, second Line of Code, replace XX with YY and you are good to go ;)"

Comment: I spelled out `LOAD DATA`, but without the specifics for your table.  And gave you a reference to the manual page.

Comment: I asked about a Solution for my **Java** Application, not for an alternative SQL Solution.